# Can I put my Database.SetInitializer call in the context constructor with the base string instead of a static constructor?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constructor, codedom

I am using Entity Framework to store some entities generated at run time using Codedom. I am actually also creating my contexts dynamically using Codedom too. Before I started dynamically generating contexts I was using a hardcoded context. The start of this hardcoded context class (up to the constructors) looked like this:

```
public class EntityModelContext : DbContext, IEntityRegistry
{
    static EntityModelContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EntityModelContext>());
    }

    public EntityModelContext()
        : base("EntityModelContext")
    {
        EntityToRegisterDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Assembly>();
    }
```

This was all good. However, I tried generating this using Codedom and discovered that static isn't a thing with Codedom. Even if I could generate a static constructor, I was getting an error which basically said that there are two constructors and I don't know which one to use. So then I merged these two constructors in my Codedom generated context class, and it now looks like this (note it's called TreeContext because I am creating a context for every entity I make and I'm making a tree entity with it in my tests):

```
TreeContext() : 
        base("TreeContext")
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TreeContext>());
    EntityToRegisterDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Assembly>();
}
```

I just tried running a test which generates a tree entity class and an instance of this tree entity, as well as the corresponding tree context class and an instance of this tree context. I tried inserting this tree entity instance into the tree context instance and it seems to have worked in SQL Server. Therefore I guess the constructor works. However, I wanted to make sure with anyone else who understands better how Database.SetInitializer works. I thought it had to be called before the base connection string is called, but it seems to work. Anyway I have only tested inserting an entity instance. I haven't tried changing the model or anything more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetInitializer where you want. Usually is in the static constructor of the context because is static.

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(...);
```

Usually is called when you first access context functions (is not enough to create the context). Usually at first read or at first SaveChanges.

You can also generate a static constructor with CodeDom with CodeTypeConstructor instead of CodeContructor.